# Django Admin: Can I create a field that can only be used if a specific choice has been picked in a previous field on the same model?

Tags: python, django

I would like to be able to set access to one field based on what was chosen in a previous field on the same model. Ideally so it can be used in the admin interface.

My model looks like so:

```
GENDER_CHOICES = (
    ('f', 'Female'),
    ('m', 'Male'),
)

class Animal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    is_castrated = models.BooleanField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Can I restrict access, specifically in the admin, to the `is_castrated` field so that it is only available when the user has chosen `Male` from the gender field?

Comment: are you looking for a dynamic solution, such as it being grayed out or not shown until Male is chosen?

Comment: @j_sqyk Yes that would be ideal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like your going to need some javascript.
You can do this by adding a bit to your admin.py file.
Check out this:

> [ModelAdmin Media Defniitions](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-media-definitions) - 
>   There are times where you would like
>   add a bit of CSS and/or JavaScript to
>   the add/change views. This can be
>   accomplished by using a Media inner
>   class on your ModelAdmin:

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        css = {
             "all": ("my_styles.css",)
         }
        js = ("my_code.js",)
```